# Setting the rowHeight of a single tile in mat-grid-list (Angular 6)

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have an `mat-grid-list` that contains an n number of `mat-card` items. At the bottom of the grid, I want to add my own custom paginator that is centred within the page (for various reasons I don't want to use the `mat-paginator` if at all possible).

I've tried simply adding a `<div>` element underneath the `mat-grid-list` element and setting the margin to `0 auto;` (which is what I'd normally do to centre a `div`) but that doesn't seem to work (the paginator remains stubbornly left-aligned).

I can add a new tile to the `mat-grid-list` that appears after all the other tiles and set its `[colspan]` equal to the number of columns. When I do this, I get a perfectly centred paginator except that there is a huge amount of excess height (presumably because it is using the height of the other `mat-grid-tile` items which are quite large).

Is there a way to either: a) get the paginator to center-align in its own `div` or b) change the `rowHeight` of a single `mat-grid-tile` so I don't end up with a ridiculous amount of white space around the paginator? Markup is below:

**`mat-grid-list` with paginator in `div`**

```
<div *ngIf="dataModel" class="container page-content">
  <mat-grid-list cols="5">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let page of dataModel.pages" [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="1">
      <mat-card >
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>{{ page.title }}</mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <img mat-card-image src="{{ this.imageBase + page.id.trim() + '.jpg' }}" alt="Photo of page" />
        <mat-card-content>
          {{ page.matches }}
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
          <button mat-button routerLink="{{ '/page/' + page.id.trim() }}">VIEW</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
  <div class="paginator">
    <button mat-icon-button [disabled]="this.currentIndex == 1" (click)="onNavClick(this.currentIndex - 1)" >
      <mat-icon aria-label="Previous">navigate_before</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of this.getPageArray(); let i = index;">
      <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" (click)="onNavClick(i + 1)">{{ i + 1 }}</button>
    </ng-container>
    <button mat-icon-button [disabled]="this.currentIndex == this.dataModel.totalPageResults" (click)="onNavClick(this.currentIndex + 1)">
      <mat-icon aria-label="Next">navigate_next</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS for .paginator class**

```
.paginator {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

(Note: I've also tried setting `display` to `inline-block` and the `width` to `100%` and neither worked).

**`mat-grid-list with paginator in a separate`mat-grid-tile`**

```
<div *ngIf="dataModel" class="container page-content">
  <mat-grid-list cols="5">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let page of dataModel.pages" [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="1">
      <mat-card >
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>{{ page.title }}</mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <img mat-card-image src="{{ this.imageBase + page.id.trim() + '.jpg' }}" alt="Photo of page" />
        <mat-card-content>
          {{ page.matches }}
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
          <button mat-button routerLink="{{ '/page/' + page.id.trim() }}">VIEW</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="5">
      <button mat-icon-button [disabled]="this.currentIndex == 1" (click)="onNavClick(this.currentIndex - 1)" >
        <mat-icon aria-label="Previous">navigate_before</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of this.getPageArray(); let i = index;">
        <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" (click)="onNavClick(i + 1)">{{ i + 1 }}</button>
      </ng-container>
      <button mat-icon-button [disabled]="this.currentIndex == this.dataModel.totalPageResults" (click)="onNavClick(this.currentIndex + 1)">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Next">navigate_next</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the rowspan of the separate tile to, for example, .5 (or anything that fits better).
I'm not sure it works with this syntax, but it works in my case, where I set `rowHeight` on the `mat-grid-list` explicitly and use `rows: .5` for the particular tile in the tiles list.